# how to remove the id attributr of element in a div jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to remove attribute id="latlongclicked from input type text using jquery

```
<div id="divloc">
  <hr>
  <label>Address(optional)</label>
  <!--<label class=" remove  btn " >Remove</label>-->   
  <input name="addr[]" class=" form-control" type="text"  placeholder="Address"></input>

  <label>Location(required)</label>
  <input name="loc[]" class="form-control" type="text" required="true" placeholder="Location" id="latlongclicked" name="location"  readonly></input>
  <p class="description" style="font-size:10px;">Click on google map to set your location </p 
</div>
```

Comment: [$.removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `removeAttr` function:

```
$('#latlongclicked').removeAttr('id');
```

http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/